# Change Input Field Value using Hook Form Alter (User Login Block)

Tags: forms

How would I go about changing the input field value from e.g. 15 to 10 in the default User Login Block for Username and Password fields, using Hook Form Alter?

Comment: Whats the question ? You want to change ? or you want to know what happens after its changing ?

Comment: I want to change the input field value for username and password in the User Login Block from 15 to 10. But I don't want to create a new template file, I want to use the Hook Form Alter option.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Put this in your module:

```
function mymodule_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id) {
  if ($form_id == 'user_login_block') {
    $form['name']['#size'] = 10;
    $form['pass']['#size'] = 10;
  }
}
```

Also hook_form_user_login_block_alter can be used, then you don't need to check the form_id.

Remember to clear the cache, if you are not already using hook_form_alter.